# EPS to JPG Converter

Tags: c#, .net, eps

Anyone know of a good library to wrap via c# to convert EPS to JPG Files?

Answer (score 1):

You could load an external library in and run function calls through that - it doesn't need to be coded in C#.

Something like ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Paint.Net's source http://getpaint.net  They might have something there for you.

Comment: The source is no longer available since the 3.0 release.

Comment: If anyone has an old copy laying around please share :)

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Pig mentioned ImageMagick - this was my first thought as well.  A Google search revealed [MagickNet](http://midimick.com/magicknet/), a .Net wrapper for this which may be of use to you.

***Edit***: Google is reporting that link as being infected with adware - the link seems valid, though.